# Table missing... or not (MYSQL)?

Tags: mysql

Suddenly I've a strange problem with Mysql:
In the navigator I see the "company" table (even after refresh), but if I do `SELECT * FROM company;` says that the table does not exist.
With the command `SHOW TABLES FROM smartex_develop;` the table "company" is present, but if I use the command `SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'smartex_develop';` the table is missing. It's very strange also considering that there are a lot of table with a foreign key of that table.
Someone know how to resolve it?

`[SELECT * FROM company]` [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqPJP.png)

`[SHOW TABLES FROM smartex_develop]` [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2p2E.png)

`[SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'smartex_develop']` [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHMoH.png)

Comment: Looks like the table's tablespace is lost (its file was deleted from disk?) - check this.

Comment: I'm not very expert, if you mean company.frm file it exists and I've just found this error in the mysql log:
[ERROR] Cannot find or open table smartex_develop/company from
the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the
table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data
files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files
of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database?
or, the table contains indexes that this version of the engine
doesn't support.

Comment: .frm is metadata file - it stores the info about table structure. The table data is stored in .ibd file - does `company.ibd` file exists in `smartex_develop` database directory? PS. What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: In smartex_develop directory there isn't any single .ibd file. But other table works fine.
The version is 5.5

Comment: *In smartex_develop directory there isn't any single .ibd file.* Check `SELECT @@innodb_file_per_table;` output... I think that it is not set. If so then try to repair general tablespace. But this can remove this table at all - maybe it is useful to search for some tool which can extract table data from raw MySQL data file, without the server?

Comment: Zero entries.
The database with the problem is local, now I'm trying to import tables and datas from the remote one but during import it says table company already exist, should I just delete the .frm file or something else?

Comment: *should I just delete the .frm file or something else?* Try to stop server, rename file (for example, to company.frm.bak) then restart server. After server starts check its logs - maybe InnoDB recovery was executed, if true then investigate the results. And one more - if some tables have FK to problematic table then remove this FK before the operation.

Comment: Omg, file company.frm disappeared from the directory and there isn't in the trash...
I'll think I'll just re-import the whole db... Ty for your time Akina

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem - a table suddenly went missing. In the logs we had:

```
Load table <name-of-missing-table> failed, the table has missing foreign key indexes. Turn off 'foreign_key_checks' and try again.

InnoDB: Foreign Key referenced table <name-of-missing-table> not found for foreign table <some-other-table>
```

This happened upon mysqld startup, so the root cause might have been much older than that. In our case, the root cause was charset conversions. We converted a few tables, and ended up with foreign keys where the column in one table and the column in the referenced table had different character sets.

How we solved:

- Disable foreign key checks
- Restart mysql -- the missing table will now reappear
- Convert all the columns that reference each other to have the same character set. You can use this query: `select table_name,column_name,CHARACTER_SET_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_schema = 'myschema' and data_type='varchar';`
- Re-enable foreign key checks
- Restart mysql -- all should be fine now